# Count bits used in int

Tags: java, math, binary, bit-manipulation

If you have the binary number 10110 how can I get it to return 5? e.g a number that tells how many bits are used? There are some likewise examples listed below:

- 101 should return 3
- 000000011 should return 2
- 11100 should return 5
- 101010101 should return 9

How can this be obtained the easiest way in Java? I have come up with the following method but can i be done faster:

```
public static int getBitLength(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int l = 1;
    if (value >>> 16 > 0) { value >>= 16; l += 16; }
    if (value >>> 8 > 0) { value >>= 8; l += 8; }
    if (value >>> 4 > 0) { value >>= 4; l += 4; }
    if (value >>> 2 > 0) { value >>= 2; l += 2; }
    if (value >>> 1 > 0) { value >>= 1; l += 1; }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: in java an int always uses 32 bits

Comment: It looks like you manually unrolled a loop, there.

Comment: The title is misleading because all 32 bits are always used in an int.

Comment: I know the title is a little misleading but I don't know what to call it, if you have a suggestion please send it and I will edit the title.

Comment: Note this is same as `log2(value)+1` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305059/how-do-you-calculate-log-base-2-in-java-for-integers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easiest?

```
32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value)
```

If you are looking for algorithms, the implementors of the Java API agree with your divide-and-conquer bitshifting approach:

```
public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(int i) {
    if (i == 0)
        return 32;
    int n = 1;
    if (i >>> 16 == 0) { n += 16; i <<= 16; }
    if (i >>> 24 == 0) { n +=  8; i <<=  8; }
    if (i >>> 28 == 0) { n +=  4; i <<=  4; }
    if (i >>> 30 == 0) { n +=  2; i <<=  2; }
    n -= i >>> 31;
    return n;
}
```

**Edit**: As a reminder to those who trust in the accuracy of floating point calculations, run the following test harness:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        long x = 1L << i;
        check(x);
        check(x-1);
    }
}

static void check(long x) {
    int correct = 64 - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(x);
    int floated = (int) (1 + Math.floor(Math.log(x) / Math.log(2)));
    if (floated != correct) {
        System.out.println(Long.toString(x, 16) + " " + correct + " " + floated);
    }
}
```

The first detected deviation is:

```
ffffffffffff 48 49
```

Comment: The first solution is the best one :)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no `Integer.bitLength()` method that would give you the answer directly.

An analogous method exists for `BigInteger`, so you could use that one:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(value).bitLength()
```

Constructing the `BigInteger` object will make it somewhat less efficient, but that will only matter if you do it many millions of times.

Answer (score 2):

You want to compute the base 2 logarithm of the number - specifically:

```
1 + floor(log2(value))
```

Java has a Math.log method which uses base e, so you can do:

```
1 + Math.floor(Math.log(value) / Math.log(2))
```

Comment: @meriton - Reasonably sure! The only problem is for a value of 0, when you end up with negative infinities and other nice things :)

Comment: Another certain problem are negative numbers, which have the highest bit set.

Comment: You are lucky, the rounding errors manifest only beyond the range of `int`. However, for `0xffffffffffffL`, your code would yield the incorrect result of 49, instead of 48. I'll add the test code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful what you ask for.  One very fast technique is to do a table lookup:

```
int bittable [] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, ... };
int numbits (int v)
{
    return bittable [v];
}
```

where `bittable` contains an entry for every int.  Of course that has complications for negative values.  A more practical way would be to count the bits in bitfields of the number

```
int bittable [16] = {0, 1, 1, 2,  1, 2, 2, 3,  1, 2, 2, 3,  2, 3, 3, 4};
int numbits (int v)
{
    int s = 0;
    while (v != 0)
    {
         s += bittable [v & 15];
         v >>= 4;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this counting set bits, rather than finding the index of the highest set bit?

Answer (score 1):

You really just want to find the position of the highest bit that is a 1. See [this page](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html), under the heading "Finding integer log base 2 of an integer (aka the position of the highest bit set)".

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://discuss.techinterview.org/default.asp?interview.11.288979.14), a way to do it with just bitwise-and and addition:

```
int GetHighestBitPosition(int value) {
  if (value == 0) return 0;

  int position = 1;
  if ((value & 0xFFFF0000) == 0) position += 16;
  if ((value & 0xFF00FF00) == 0) position += 8;
  if ((value & 0xF0F0F0F0) == 0) position += 4;
  if ((value & 0xCCCCCCCC) == 0) position += 2;
  if ((value & 0xAAAAAAAA) == 0) position += 1;

  return position;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer.toBinaryString(value).length()

Answer (score 0):

I think the rounded-up log_2 of that number will give you what you need.

Something like:

```
return (int)(Math.log(value) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
```

Comment: @meriton: I think so. See Chris's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int CountBits(uint value)
{
    for (byte i = 32; i > 0; i--)
    {
        var b = (uint)1 << (i - 1);
        if ((value & b) == b)
            return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the fastest (and without a table, which is certainly faster), this is probably the one:

```
public static int bitLength(int i) {
    int len = 0;

    while (i != 0) {
        len += (i & 1);
        i >>>= 1;
    }

    return len;

}
```

Comment: Why are you &'ing the len? @ 'len += (i & 1)'. Wouldn't this just give you a count on all the 1's in a bit string?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the `length()` of a `BitSet` which according to the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length--)

> Returns the "logical size" ... the index of
>        the highest set bit ... plus one.

To use the `BitSet` you need to create an array. So it is not as simple as starting with a pure `int`. But you get it out of the JDK box - tested and supported. It would look like this:

```
  public static int bitsCount(int i) {
    return BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { i }).length();
  }
```

Applied to the examples in the question:

```
  bitsCount(0b101); // 3
  bitsCount(0b000000011); // 2
  bitsCount(0b11100); // 5
  bitsCount(0b101010101); // 9
```

When asking for bits the `BitSet`seems to me to be the appropriate data structure.