# Log base 2 in Java for doubles

Tags: java, math, entropy

I'm trying to calculate the entropy of English using the following Java function

```
public static void calculateEntropy()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < letterFrequencies[i]; i++)
        {
            entropy += letterFrequencies[i] * (Math.log(letterFrequencies[i])/Math.log(2));
        }
        entropy *= -1;
    }
```

The formula I'm using requires log base 2 but Java only has natural log and log base 10. I'm trying to use the change of base formula to get the log base 2 of letterFrequencies[i]. I do not know if I am implementing it correctly because I'm expecting an answer close to 4.18 but instead getting roughly .028

Comment: @turbo OP's using this formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base

Comment: Probably not a dup but related to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3305059/1065197

Comment: Make sure all the other pieces actually work as expected. You could be trying to solve the wrong problem. I'd remove the log part to check if values are what is expected.

Comment: What are the contents of `letterFrequencies`?

Comment: `i < letterFrequencies[i]` Is this correct? Isn't it `i < letterFrequencies.length`?

Comment: It's supposed to be letterFrequencies.length. That was my problem

Comment: You could also use the for-each loop that is available for all collection types in Java. Something like `for(double freq : letterFrequencies) {entropy +=freq*Math.log(freq); } entropy /= -Math.log(2);`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `for`'s stop condition:

`i < letterFrequencies[i]` should be `i < letterFrequencies.length`.

Furthermore, I'd use [Guava's DoubleMath.log2() method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/DoubleMath.html#log2(double)), which is optimized as @LutzL suggested.

Answer (score -3):

Mathematically that implementation is correct, but it doesn't work out in code. You could instead write your own implementation, witch runs significantly faster:

```
public static int log2(int n){
    if(n <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n);
}
```

Source: [How do you calculate log base 2 in Java for integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305059/how-do-you-calculate-log-base-2-in-java-for-integers)

Comment: *Yes, that is a correct implementation of log2* mathematically it's correct, but programatically it isn't.

Comment: Yes. That's also explained in the question from where you obtained the piece of code you posted.

Comment: Is it ok to edit my answer like this? (I'm new to stackoverflow)

Comment: return value gives you Math.floor(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2))