# How to convert char 'A' to binary '1010' in java language

Tags: java, binary, char, hex, decimal

I want to convert character type to binary but not char byte to bit.

I'll show you example.

if char = 'A' but actually it's hex! A = 1010
I have a character type but I want to represent it like hexadecimal.

Of course, I have only character data that can be matched hexadecimal. 
like 9, 8, A, C, D   not 47, U, Y ..

And Can I count size or length of 1 in 1010 ?

If you know how to solve this please let me know thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a textbook example of "Do my thing for me"

Comment: Do you mean `Long.toString(Long.parseString(str, 16), 2)` ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [how to convert a char from alphabetical character to hexadecimal number in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477714/how-to-convert-a-char-from-alphabetical-character-to-hexadecimal-number-in-java) specifically "To read hex and convert to binary you can do..." (messed up my close vote...)

Comment: @PeterLawrey `Long.parseLong`

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you mean by _And Can I count size or length of 1 in 1010_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477714/how-to-convert-a-char-from-alphabetical-character-to-hexadecimal-number-in-java

Comment: To "_count size or length of 1 in 1010_" see: [Count bits used in int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935793/count-bits-used-in-int)

Answer (score 2):

### Simple Steps

Here you can convert any Alphabet to the binary number

```
System.out.println(Long.toString(Long.parseLong("A", 16), 2)); //Output 1010
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can most easily (and probably most efficiently) use `Character.digit()`.

```
    int a = Character.digit('A', 16);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the input is a `char`, convert using the helper method from `Character`:

```
int num = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
```

Then convert it to a binary string:

```
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(num);
```